# Scrape CSS informations with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from the web which contain website URL. And I would like to know if there is a way to be aware if the website is responsive with beautifulSoup? More specially, can we check the CSS code with BeautifulSoup or you're restricted with the HTML.

The CSS from a responsive website would contain something like "@media" by example.

Is there a way to check it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` is an *HTML parser*, it does not understand the CSS syntax. Depending on the structure of the target page and where the `@media` is defined, you may parse it with `BeautifulSoup`, extract the stylesheet URL(s), download it(them) with, say, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and parse it with, for instance, [`tinycss`](http://pythonhosted.org/tinycss/) looking for `@media` rule(s).